# Make dictionary from a string inside a cell of Pandas data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Pandas data-frame (`df`) has some strings in a column (`m`)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"m": ['0 = absence\n1 = mild\n2 = moderate \n3 = severe','0 = no \n1 = yes\n2 = Not relevant','1: smoker\n2: ex-smoker (not smoked)'], "c": [1,1,1], "x":[5,3,6]})
```

This creates the following data-frame:

[image]

Now, I need to split each string in the column `m` first by `\n` and then by `=` or `:`, to make it a dictionary like this:

[image]

Is there any compact way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like here is [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) method needed:

```
import re

df.loc[:, 'm'] = df['m'].map(lambda x: dict(map(lambda y: re.split(' = |: ', y), x.split('\n'))))
```

Output wee be like:

```
                                                   m  c  x
0  {'0': 'absence', '1': 'mild', '2': 'moderate '...  1  5
1      {'0': 'no ', '1': 'yes', '2': 'Not relevant'}  1  3
2     {'1': 'smoker', '2': 'ex-smoker (not smoked)'}  1  6
```

If the key is required as a number, you can add additional line:

```
df.loc[:, 'm'] = df['m'].map(lambda x: {int(k): v for k, v in x.items()})
```

Output:

```
                                                   m  c  x
0  {0: 'absence', 1: 'mild', 2: 'moderate ', 3: '...  1  5
1            {0: 'no ', 1: 'yes', 2: 'Not relevant'}  1  3
2         {1: 'smoker', 2: 'ex-smoker (not smoked)'}  1  6
```

Comment: Good use of `map`. +1.

Comment: Works. But showing a warning.


SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.

Comment: @ghosh'. yeah, just change `df['m']` to `df.loc[:, 'm']`. Answer was updated